# how to make json string of the chechbox checked div text

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

how to make json string with jquery on button click but text should be whose chechbox checked.

**These are Dynamically Created div**

```
<div class="div1">
    <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" value="1">
    <div class="divdata">divtext1</div>
    <span class="spandata">spantext1</span>
</div>
<div class="div1">
    <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" value="1">
    <div class="divdata">divtext2</div>
    <span class="spandata">spantext2</span>
</div>
<div class="div1">
    <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" value="1">
    <div class="divdata">divtext3</div>
    <span class="spandata">spantext3</span>
</div>
<input type="submit" id="btndisplay" value="Display Data">
```

**This is Desire output want in a textarea**

```
<textarea>
    {
        "mydata":[
            {"divdata":"divtext1", "spandata":"spantext1"}, 
            {"divdata":"divtext2", "spandata":"spantext2"}, 
            {"divdata":"divtext3", "spandata":"spantext3"}
        ]
    }
</textarea>
```

**jQuery code**

```
$("#btndisplay").click(function(){
    var divdata = $('.div1 input[type=checkbox]:checked').siblings('.divdata').text();
    var spandata = $('.div1 input[type=checkbox]:checked').siblings('.spandata').text();
    $('textarea').append(....); // here i am not getting understand.
});
```

Comment: i want div and span data in array whose checkbox is checked

Comment: the last part : `textarea.value=JSON.stringify(collection, null, "\t")` the first part is from a .map() of `querySelectorAll(".div1")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what you are wanting is along these lines.

JS

```
$('#btndisplay').click(function(){
  var obj = {
    "myData": []
  };

  $('.div1').each(function() {
    if($(this).find('.checkbox').is(':checked')) {

      obj["myData"].push({
        'divdata': $(this).find('.divdata').text(),
        'spandata': $(this).find('.spandata').text()
      });

    }
  });

  $('textarea').val(JSON.stringify(obj));
});
```

See js fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/23pf5t10/4/